# Cluster a time series by labels

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a time series, tab delimited dataset with the following format

```
Label4  0.064463    0.063448    0.070535    0.080498    0.055382    0.054336    0.055336
Label3  0.068560    0.091277    0.103625    0.092759    0.069522    0.070261    0.068328
Label2  0.058401    0.057793    0.062452    0.065339    0.044136    0.069419    0.049345
Label1  0.091222    0.093995    0.097264    0.108168    0.073451    0.071705    0.092312
...
```

I want to cluster the data by rows, such that a cluster is a group of rows that have similar numbers for column 1 - column 7.

I would like the output of FindCluster to  return only the first column (Label). I do not want FindCluster to use the data in column 1 in the actual clustering calculation.

This is an incorrect implementation:

```
data=ImportString["Label4   0.064463    0.063448    0.070535    0.080498    0.055382    0.054336    0.055336
Label3  0.068560    0.091277    0.103625    0.092759    0.069522    0.070261    0.068328
Label2  0.058401    0.057793    0.062452    0.065339    0.044136    0.069419    0.049345
Label1  0.091222    0.093995    0.097264    0.108168    0.073451    0.071705    0.092312","TSV"];
clusters = FindClusters[{data[[All, Range[2, 8]]]} -> {data[[All, 1]]}]
```

My ideal output would be something like

> ```
> {{Label1, Label2}, {Label3, Label4}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
data2 = ToExpression /@ {##2} -> #1 & @@ # & /@ (StringSplit @@@ data);
```

> ```
> {{0.064463, 0.063448, 0.070535, 0.080498, 0.055382, 0.054336, 0.055336} -> "Label4", 
>  {0.06856, 0.091277, 0.103625, 0.092759, 0.069522,  0.070261, 0.068328} -> "Label3", 
>  {0.058401, 0.057793, 0.062452, 0.065339, 0.044136, 0.069419, 0.049345} -> "Label2", 
>  {0.091222, 0.093995, 0.097264, 0.108168, 0.073451, 0.071705, 0.092312} -> "Label1"}
> ```

```
clusters = FindClusters[data2];
(* {{"Label4","Label2"},{"Label3","Label1"}} *)
```

for the data you provided:

```
data = ImportString[
   "Label4   0.064463    0.063448    0.070535    0.080498    0.055382   0.054336    0.055336
   Label3  0.068560    0.091277    0.103625    0.092759    0.069522    0.070261    0.068328
   Label2  0.058401    0.057793    0.062452    0.065339    0.044136    0.069419    0.049345
   Label1  0.091222    0.093995    0.097264    0.108168    0.073451   0.071705    0.092312", 
   "TSV"];
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @JustinGardin, my pleasure. Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please consider visiting the [tour page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) on the basic rules of the site, and
[editing help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for editing help.